# Loading an image in WP8 app on device

Tags: c#, image, resources, windows-phone-8, image-loading

i am trying to make a simple application in which i have an image i have copied it in Assets folder of my project. The image i got from the web, and it is in the png format.

can some body give me an idea that how i can copy my images to my project so that when i deploy the project on device i will able to load them.

Current i what i am trying is.

```
   var streamResource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/gradiant-mask.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    using (Stream stream = streamResource.Stream) {
                        var maskData = new byte[stream.Length];
                        stream.Read(maskData, 0, maskData.Length);
}
```

But i always get the `streamResource` object as `null` and the may be the reason is it didn't find the file on the device. can some body guide me that how i can load the image on the device in my wp8 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `Build action` is set to `Content` on the properties of the image file in Visual Studio.

If you want the `Build action` to be set to `Resource`, use the following URI syntax:

```
new Uri("/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME;component/Assets/Tiles/gradiant-mask.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Using the `Content` build action is recommended.

Comment: i am still getting the same `null` value in the resource stream. what i am doing now is some thing like this :   var rStream = App.GetresourceStrea(new Uri("/PhoneApp4;component/Assets/Tiles/gradiant-mask.png", UriKind.Relative));   but no benefits. any idea? and what do you mean by Build action to be set to Resource ???

Comment: In VS Solution Explorer, right click on the image file => Properties => Build action.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly load image by :
in XAML

```
Source="/Assets/Tiles/gradiant-mask.png"
```

or in code behind by

```
imagename.Source = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/gradiant-mask.png",UriKind.Relative);
```

set the build action as `content` .

Comment: i actually want to do some editing on image and that's why i want stream from the image file. I do not want to load it in some image control.